# how to deal with the Generic in Kotlin from java code

Tags: android, kotlin

code in java:

```
public interface MvpPresenter<V extends MvpView> {
  public void attachView(V view);
  public void detachView(boolean retainInstance);
}
```

when I write in kotlin:

```
interface MvpPresenter<out MvpView> {
    fun attachView(view: MvpView)
    fun detachView(retainInstance: Boolean)
}
```

**fun attachView(view: V)** compile error!
So How can I deal with **? extend T** in kotlin???

Comment: how to deal with upper bound  but can use as java code?

Answer (score 0):

You use `<V: MvpView>`!

Also change the declaration of `attachView` to:

```
fun attachView(view: V)
```

That's defining an upper bound for the generic type `V`.

> So How can I deal with ? extend T in kotlin???

That seems to be somewhat unrelated because you are now talking about generic wildcards. In kotlin, `<? extends MvpView>` would be `<out MvpView>`

Comment: but if I use in, I make a new class LoginView : MvpView, the LoginView is not include in MvpView

Comment: @user3163839 I realised that was wrong and edited. Did you not see it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try again

Comment: I am sorry ,I mean how to deal with upper bound but can use as java code?

Comment: @user3163839 can it not be used as Java code with my solution? What error does it produce?

Comment: class BaseActivity<P : BasePresenter<*, *>> : AppCompatActivity()